# iPhone 6 landing page using HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got rather broad question. Is it possible to create simplified version of: http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/buy-iphone/iphone6 landing page using only html/css?

Key feature would be the option menu, when you'd pick desired color and capacity and after all is selected a button would appear to forward to corresponding product. Button would direct to a product according to what you choose above in options. 2nd option line should be inactive, when nothing is chosen in the 1st line. Image could be just static.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it, but it would require a lot of repetitive work. Each of the buttons would redirect to another HTML page, based on the user's choice. So you would basically need to create at least 10 HTML pages, each with it's on phone picture, other choices, etc. for each button choice. As for the popup boxes, you'd need JS. If I were you, I'd just learn JavaScript.

Comment: And how hard would it be to do that using js? I imagine only basic js is required?

Comment: Yes, pretty basic JS. I suggest you pick up a Head First JS Programming book, read a few chapters, and you'd be set. It's pretty easy. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With HTML you can only describe the markup of a website (layout).
With CSS you can do the layout, the style, animations and little actions like "hover", etc..

What you want is logic and there is no way to implement logic into a website without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There's some trickery you can do with CSS inputs and their labels. Basically you set the options as the label attached to a hidden checkbox. Then you do some CSS if the checkbox is checked. Look at this silly game: http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/hBaqo

It's basically labels floating around, and if you click the label, its checkbox gets checked, and the CSS recognizes that and performs some other styling to make it work. I'm not going to work that out for your specific scenario, but this should give you an option to look at.

```
<input class="input-option" type="radio" id="option1" >
<label for="option1">Put your option 1 here. When someone clicks the label, the input will be checked.</label>
```

You can show different background images depending on what's checked.

```
#option1:checked #option4:checked ~ .imagecontainer { background-image:url(foo.bar) }
```